# Проблема с java: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, linux-mint

Сегодня первый день на linuxMint установил сначала jdk через терминал, потом установил еще один через iDea, все работает, на при запуске программы внутри idea вмести с выводом выкидывает данную строку "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/boris/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/cache/tmp/"
Уже успел прочитать, что это потому, что не правильно настроены системные переменные, но если вбить в терминал java -version выдает корректную версию моего jdk.
Что это может быть и как с этим бороться?

Comment: А зачем второй jdk ставили? Оставьте только 1 и используйте его

Comment: Так idea ничего не знает о втором jdk